# Create dockercfg secret via template

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I'm trying to create a secret for a private docker repository. This secret should be packaged in a template and the access data should be passed through template parameters. In principle I need a YAML template variant for the following oc command:

```
oc secrets new-dockercfg privaterepository --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Comment: Try `oc get secret privaterepository -o yaml --export`. Then just replace the actual secret values with parameters. Make sure that in the description, you make it obvious that the values have to already be base64 encoded

Comment: Already tried this. But this results in a base64-encoded dockercfg string. So I'm not able to fill the values from template parameters. https://pastebin.com/raw/8u6jwJFv

Comment: It doesn't have to be base64 encoded on the way in if you set them in the `stringData` section instead of `data` section. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html#dev-guide-secrets-using-secrets

Comment: It is also worthwhile running the `oc` command with ``--loglevel 9``. You can then see what resource description it is creating to ensure you are getting it correct.

Comment: Running the oc command results in the same base64 encoded string: https://pastebin.com/raw/sjqBybi0